How to fix transparent background of Angular Material components?
I have upgraded my Angular 14 to Angular 16. I have did it in two steps, firstly I upgraded it to 15 then I upgraded it to 16. Along with Angular itself I have upgraded Angular Material from 14 to 16.
Now, I see dialog box are shown while they are transparent and their behind things can be seen. They are mostly mat-menu-item and mat-dialog.
I played with Matrial version and upgraded and downgraded. But nothing happened. Also checked the browsers console for any errors but did not find anything useful.
At the moment I am clueless. I highly appreciate it if anyone can help me.
I upgraded Angular 14 to Angular 15 then upgraded to Angular 16. Did same for Angular Material from 14 to 16. I expected dialog boxes to be shown without their behind elements be visible.
